# generate associative array json from php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Expected JSON structure:

```
{"music" : [ 
    { 
        "title" : "Jazz in Paris",
        "album" : "Jazz & Blues"
    },
    { 
        "title" : "Jazz in Paris",
        "album" : "Jazz & Blues"
    }
    .......
    .......
]}
```

Current JSON:

```
{"music":{"title":"Origin of evil","album":"devotional"}}
```

Code:

```
$sub = array();
foreach ($this->data as  $value)
{
    $sub['title'] = $value['title'];
    $sub['album'] = "devotional";
}
$audio = array('music'=>$sub);
echo json_encode($audio);
```

Comment: You need to wrap whole array in another array.

Comment: for the associative structure of the `music` part of array you need to add extra array here, the example given by the alokPatel as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an array outside of the `foreach` and then append the `subarray` into main array using `[]`.

Like this,

```
$audio=array();
$audio["music"]=array();
foreach ($this->data as  $value)
        {
            $sub = array();
            $sub['title'] = $value['title'];
            $sub['album'] = "devotional";
            $audio["music"][]=$sub;
        }

echo json_encode($audio);
```

This will create an array of music and each sub array as a object of it.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap things in another array. just change `echo json_encode(array($audio));`

```
$sub = array();
foreach ($this->data as  $value)
{
    $sub['title'] = $value['title'];
    $sub['album'] = "devotional";
}
$audio = array('music'=>array($sub)); // just add array so whole things are wrap in another array.

echo json_encode($audio);
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok. oh yeah brother it was my mistake thanks for point it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Change a bit in your existing code-

Just add extra array to the `$sub` as `array($sub)`.

```
$audio = array('music'=>array($sub));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
    $sub = array();
    foreach ($this->data as  $value)
    {
        $temp['title'] = $value['title'];
        $temp['album'] = "devotional";
        array_push($sub, $temp);
    }
    $audio = array('music'=>$sub);
    echo json_encode($audio);
```